# Composer / Symfony: add modules dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a monolith Symfony 6 application. Now I'd like a way for end-users to extend the application in a way similar to Drupal and its module ecosystem.

One way would be to tell users to run a `composer install myproject/myextension`, wherein extensions are classic Symfony bundles. The problem with this, however, is that it breaks the idea of being able to deploy a single Docker image since effectively once an end-user wants to upgrade the container image, they would have to run the install command again for each module.

So, my thought was to simply add a folder "plugins" to the Composer autoload configuration (by rolling my own plugin discovery that then adapts the composer.json `autload.psr-4` key) - but that only makes classes loadable, does not initialize Symfony-specific things (e.g. bundle configuration, Twig template paths, ...) and I have to roll my own discovery mechanism (so that the admin user can go to a "Modules" page and see/enable plugins extracted in the folder).

Does canonical Symfony already bring in an actual "dynamic" plugin mechanism that I can use or do I really have to go the hard way and create a mechanism from scratch that not just edits `composer.json` but also `config/bundles.php`?

Comment: There is no Symfony supplied dynamic plugin mechanism and as you can tell, developing such a system is not an easy task.  I know it may sound a bit funny but if you want a mature plugin system then consider using WordPress.

Comment: By the way, these sorts of questions are not really good fits for stackoverflow.  Might consider posting on the [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/) board.

Answer (score 0):

The discovery system could be something hard to implement.

It can be easy if you provide your own repo...

https://getcomposer.org/doc

Otherwise for the installation, you can also make something like:

- select the module
- make a php script that make something like

`exec("composer install $module_name", $output)`

and you can look into $output for the response.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that is, as said, that when a user updates the docker image, they would need to re-install all the modules by hand (and additionally, it would make deployments inside a k8s environment outright impossible).